# Plotting data using matplotlib from csv but the numbers on the y-axis are not in order

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib, graph

I'm new to Python and I have been trying to plot a graph using matplotlib in PyCharm from csv file. The x-axis is months and y-axis is sales, but the numbers on the y axis are not in the right order. I have read that I need to convert it to float but it says "ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'sales' ". I think this is because in the csv file the header of the row with the sales data is 'sales' so it can't convert the word 'sales' to float. How do I make it ignore the header and convert the rest of the values to float? Or if that's not what's wrong, can someone please help me fix it?:)

This is the code I have (without my attempt to convert to float):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = []
y = []

with open('sales.csv','r') as sales_csv:
    plots = csv.reader(sales_csv, delimiter=',')
    for row in plots:
        x.append(row[1])
        y.append(row[2])

plt.plot(x, y, color='r', label='Monthly Sales 2018', marker='o')
plt.xlabel('Month')
plt.ylabel('Sales')
plt.title('Monthly Sales 2018')
plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

And please find attached a screenshot of how the graph looks like. [graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0RwSH.png)

Also, just for reference, this is the csv file (only need to plot month and sales)

```
year, month,sales,expenditure
2018,jan,6226,3808
2018,feb,1521,3373
2018,mar,1842,3965
2018,apr,2051,1098
2018,may,1728,3046
2018,jun,2138,2258
2018,jul,7479,2084
2018,aug,4434,2799
2018,sep,3615,1649
2018,oct,5472,1116
2018,nov,7224,1431
2018,dec,1812,3532
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Since the CSV has a header, you can use `csv.DictReader(sales_csv)` to read your CSV file. By default, it will read the first line in your CSV as the column names of your CSV instead of using it as a regular row. Then, when you iterate over the rows, you can use `row["month"]` and `row["sales"]` to access the appropriate columns.

```py
with open('sales.csv','r') as sales_csv:
    plots = csv.DictReader(sales_csv, delimiter=',')
    for row in plots:
        x.append(row["month"])
        y.append(float(row["sales"]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just paste your data in a file and save it as `test.csv` and run this. Note that your second column name is `' month'` and not `'month'` because the data that you've pasted as of now has a space post the comma after the first column. Either keep that and run this code or remove that and edit this code to replace `' month'` with `'month'`.

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

# paste your data into a file and save it as test.csv
# Please note that read_csv assumes that row 0 is the header, so, 
# we don't need to pass that argument for your case
data = pd.read_csv('test.csv') 

data[' month'] = data[' month'].str.title()
data['Date'] = data[' month']
# converting type from str to pandas datetime stamps
data['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Date'], format='%b')
# changing the year from 1900 (default) to 2018(desired)
data['Date'] = data['Date'].mask(data['Date'].dt.year == 1900, 
                             data['Date'] + pd.offsets.DateOffset(year=2018))

plt.plot(data['Date'], data['sales'], color='r', label='Monthly Sales 2018', marker='o')

# x-axis date representation formatting
myFmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%b')
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(myFmt)

plt.xlabel('Month')
plt.ylabel('Sales')
plt.title('Monthly Sales 2018')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

You can read more about behaviour of datetime in python at this link: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior